# Belkin 3267 adapter issues

Tags: windows-7, wireless-networking

My Belkin N adaptor disconnects randomly under Win 7 and usually doesn't reconnect.  I did not have this issue under the previous OS: Vista. And the Compaq machine with Vista never disconnects, so I'm suspecting it is linked to Win 7 issues.

> My system:
>
> Belkin wireless N adaptor on Acer with MS Windows 7 Ultimate 32-bit and Intel Pentium E2140  @ 1.60GHz, in another room a Dell XPS with Win 7 64 hooked directly with no problems to Belkin 3267 router.

Comment: There is very little information to be able to solve this issue.  There can be a myriad of issues that can be associated with this.  More information is needed to give a good answer.

Comment: Thanks for the response and the fix of my question format.  I see that someone else reports LAN ok, but wireless flaky.  Hey, I upgraded my old D-link G router to a Belkin N, and the wireless adapter to an N, but no rhyme or reason why the adapter goes bye bye.

Answer (score 0):

Here are some suggestions on how to [increase wireless network performance](http://www.itedge.net/blog/2009/06/25/increasing-wireless-network-performance-in-windows-7/) in Windows 7